# How get from Twitter api friends list who added my app?

Tags: twitter

I can get user's friends list. But i`m intresting only in user's friends who authorize my app on my site.

How i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of an authentication process (with OAuth I guess), Twitter gives you tokens for the application, the ID and the screen name (username) of the user who authorized the app.

So you can do something like this :

1. At the end of the authentication process : storing the user ID and/or the username of the user who authorized your application (in your database for example).
2. When you retrieve the user's friend list, you can see if user's friend authorized your app by watching if its ID (and/or its username, depending on what you kept) is in the storage where you keep informations about users who authorized your app.

Comment: I would be great full if you could provide an example or any reference that was done using this process.